# replace same pattern with different replace value

Tags: python, regex

I have a file like this (this is a simplified version):

```
james sfsf qef qef
qef qef qe fff
qqew james james qef
qefq ffgrsf wsef 
qef james eq james
```

I want to replace each iteration of 'james' with a different value. Here's what I have in my test code:

```
f=open('file_to_be_read.txt','r')
text=f.read()
matches=len(re.findall('james',text))
f.close()
number=0
for x in range(matches):
    new_text=re.sub(r'james',str(number),text,count=1)
    number+=1
r=open('result_file.txt','w')
r.write(new_text)
r.close()
```

But it just replaces the first 'james' with 2. Rather than produce the following result that I want:

```
1 sfsf qef qef
qef qef qe fff
qqew 2 3 qef
qefq ffgrsf wsef 
qef 4 eq 5
```

I thought that by repeating the re.sub with count=1 I would replace 1 james each time but allow me to change the replace value.

Comment: _"But it just replaces the first 'james' with 2"_. Strange. It replaces it with "4" on my machine.

Comment: You're right, in typing it up I changed my example file I was reading from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're discarding the updated string - try this:

```
text = re.sub(r'james', str(x), text, count=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a silly mistake by me. Sometimes I can't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) for this:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> import re
>>> s = '''james sfsf qef qef
qef qef qe fff
qqew james james qef
qefq ffgrsf wsef
qef james eq james'''
>>> print re.sub(r'james', lambda x, c=count(1): str(next(c)), s)
1 sfsf qef qef
qef qef qe fff
qqew 2 3 qef
qefq ffgrsf wsef
qef 4 eq 5
```

Here `c=count(1)` is a default argument value and it is going to be calculated only once(when the function object is created), next calls to this function are going to increment the previous count each time.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted another one because it was closer to the way I was doing it, but it's always nice to see more efficient solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_text=re.sub(r'james',str(number),text,count=1)
```

You are working on `text` each time.  You give it the same input text to work with, rather than processing your `new_text`.

Try this:

```
new_text = text
for x in range(matches):
    new_text=re.sub(r'james',str(number),new_text,count=1)
    number+=1
number+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` can take a function as the replacement value.  This does roughly what you want

```
import re

with open('file_to_be_read.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

number = 0
def do_replace( matchobj ):
    global number
    replacement = str(number)
    number += 1
    return replacement

new_text = re.sub(r'james', do_replace, text)

with open('result_file.txt', 'w') as r:
    r.write(new_text)
```